# Want to organize apps on nexus 4

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-4

I have many apps, i want to organize my 150 apps in folders (but not on the home screen). Any suggestions how to do this properly?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that your question (recommend some app) is [off-topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: The core problem may or may not be solved by an app, so I edited the Q to ask more broadly.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the launcher. Most stock launchers won't, but I know Nova Launcher (only Prime version) has folders in the App Drawer. It's all manually done, though.

Other launchers, which I can't name right now, can probably organize it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a difficult thing to do. You just need to use a 3rd party launcher which is highly customizable. Like Nova or Apex Launcher.

You could also give "Aviate Launcher" by YAHOO a go which automatically makes a few "categories" as your home screens. But it's nothing like the usual launcher we use so liking it or not will be upto you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes nova prime can organize in your drawer.

Comment: A link to the app and how to do it would be good.